# Linear background image doesnt work properly on safari

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
body{
  background:red;
}

div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div>
  test
</div>
```

As you can see here, it is displayed differently between chrome and safari:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apwoGj

Why is that happening?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/thing-know-gradients-transparent-black/

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, goes from white, to white with zero transparency. Seems to work the same on chrome and safari for me.

```
div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #fff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) , rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
```

Also make a solid colour background at the top just incase a browser doesn't support the gradient it will revert to the solid colour.

If you have a solid background there will be no need for transparency, use solid colours.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff, red);
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #fff, red);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #fff, red);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, red);
```

this will do a gradient from white to red as the background is red(change red to whatever your background colour is)

Comment: If you're using a solid background you wont need to use transparency, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As others have said safari on the PC is dead and should not be used because apart from the fact that is its a very old and dead browser and will support little css3 it will also be a security issue because it is not maintained. Users should remove it from their system as it has no viable use these days.

Notwithstanding the above the problem with your code is that safari 5.1 on the PC doesn't understand the new linear gradient syntax (because it wasn't around then) and you would need to use the prefixed version.

background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #DDDDDD 100%);
The above is tested and working in safari PC (I have it installed an an old machine that I don't use anymore).

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,2989d8+50,207cca+51,7db9e8+100;Blue+Gloss+Default */
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Maybe use this order and explanation from [Colorzilla gradient generator.](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) Try like this cause you might have a type somewhere we cannot see or your order is not the best one.